# Remote site and client private keys

Tags: asp.net, firefox, applet, smartcard

I have a bit of a difficult situation in that I need a way for a client connected to an ASP.NET MVC site to sign and decrypt blobs with their private key, such that the server never sees the private key material. In the decryption case, these are encrypted session keys. It is acceptable that the server see the session key, just not the users private key.

That is, I need to present the user some content in a browser, have some javascript (or java applets, or silverlight, etc.) execute client side that communicates with a hardware token on the client, and returns the result to the server.

This is NOT client side authentication. I don't need to simply authenticate via IIS with a certificate. The hardware tokens are HID OmniKey USB readers.

My understanding of the options available are:

**1. [Mozilla Javascript Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_crypto)** - This seems to be the optimal route. It appears that Firefox exposes various smart card events and functionality to remote sites. I see how to sign text, but nothing about decrypting blobs (the largest goal). There seems to be methods for loading a PKCS#11 module, but the documentation seems to stop after that.

**2. Silverlight with Elevated Trust** - This is my second preferable route, because of familiarity with Silverlight and .NET. Silverlight 5 has the ability to P/Invoke, so I could always call the PC/SC modules, but this requires running Out of Browser, which I can't do. There seems to be some posts about running a Silverlight app In Browser with elevated trust, but this is a global setting, and so I don't want to diminish security for other applications.

**3. ActiveX**  - An ActiveX component can interact with the PC/SC module, but this would be an Internet Explorer only solution. If forced to pick a required browser, I'd prefer Firefox or Chrome.

**3. Firefox/Chrome Extension** - My understanding is Firefox XPCOM is C++, and I can just directly call the PC/SC libraries, and the extension can interact with scripts/DOM on the remote site. I'm not sure how the remote site though can trigger a Firefox extension. In other words, how does the remote site tell the extension "ok, it's time to sign"? One such example of this route is [XSign](http://www.lizard-labs.net/xsign_xenc.aspx) (though it doesn't use hardware tokens).

**4. Java Applet** - This might ultimately be the only way to do it. I've found a couple examples/guides, but I'm not familiar with Java. [Java Applet for Signing with a Smart Card](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3587361/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm). In this case, it's just a simple applet that can communicate with the token, and post the results to the site.

Are there other options available? I believe option (1), Mozilla Javascript Crypto is the best approach, but the documentation is beyond sparse. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I have virtually examined all options. The last option (Java Applet) is the most appropriate for your case and easiest to implement. The downside is that JRE (Java Runtime Environment) should already be installed at client side and plays nice with the browser. User also has to grant permission to the applet to connect to his smart card at first run.

BTW if you want to use PKCS#7, you can use Bouncy Castle. It has no standard API in JDK.

PS: Don't use JavaScript for cryptography. [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider just having the clients download a native application and install it (once).  You can have them use that app to do the authentication and negotiate a session key with your server - the app could then launch a browser with the session key in the launch url. "Native" apps could probably be not that native - use java or .net (if you're windows only) or python etc.